# XML schema - extending complexType within same namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, fpml

I'm using FpML schemas, but I also want to extend it by custom elements. Due to some constraints I dont want to use different namespace for my extensions XSD.

So let's say default FpML schema has this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="FxDigitalOption">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Describes an option having a triggerable fixed payout.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:element name="effectiveDate" type="AdjustableOrRelativeDate" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Effective date for a forward starting derivative. If this element is not present, the effective date is the trade date.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="tenorPeriod" type="Period" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">A tenor expressed as a period type and multiplier (e.g. 1D, 1Y, etc.)</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However I want to add element abcd from my extensions XSD to FxDigitalOption. How can I do that?

I know how to do it by using different namespace, but somehow I cant make my extensions xsd to work with same namespace.

Comment: Please edit your question and include details of what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: ...and your xsd snippet looks wrong to me. An xsd:element cannot be a child of xsd:complexContent - you need xsd:sequence or xsd:choice.